# QListWidget of QGroupBox selecteables

Tags: qt, qgroupbox, qlistwidgetitem

Hi i'm trying to create a series of QGroupBox for a number of categories which then should be able to be modified at the request of the user, via code, I use a QScrolArea to place there the QGroupBox, so I have not had any problem, the problem is that I need that are "selectable" so I decided to place them in a QListWidget using setItemWidget (), I have no problems with that, the problem comes when selecting these items, because when you hover over the QGorupBox the "box shown selection "but to click the item not selected, I looked at other similar post but none solved my problem, Is there an easy way and without many complications to do this?
Thank you for your attention

```
void VentPrinc::recibeCajaCategoria(QGroupBox *caja){
QListWidgetItem *test = new QListWidgetItem;
test->setSizeHint(QSize(232,97));
ui->listWidgetTest->setViewMode(QListView::ListMode);
ui->listWidgetTest->addItem(test);
ui->listWidgetTest->setItemWidget(test,caja);
}
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by selecting a QGroupBox ? You clic on a QGroupBox and what happened ?

Comment: I use a QGroupBox just to display 3 QLabel QLabel text and grouped image, this represents a certain set of categories using my project, but a normal QGropuBox is not selectable, that is why i use a QGroupBox on QListWidgetItem, and to some extent it works, but every time I use setItemWidget() the QListWidgetItem make unselectable, i can pass the mouse over the list item (on QListWidget) but to click on the item, the item is not selected, now, I read that can create a custom QListWidgetItem that might contain an icon and three lines of text,but I have not managed to understand how to do this

Comment: Well, it didn't answer my question. In a QGroupBox, you can have various widgets that could be checkable. So if selectable and checkable means the same for you, it's ok. You have the `QGroupBox::setCheckable(boolean)` which can allow or not if widgets in this QGroupBox are checkable.

Comment: Well I guess I can store QGroupBox a QList or QVector, and check one of these QGroupBox is cheked on, look through the list to uncheck the rest, thank you very much :)